# How to set Receiver url to list

Tags: event-receivers

how could i set receiver list url?
I dont have like this List/myList, i have a drafts url?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
  <Receiver>
    <Name>EventMetadataItemAdding</Name>
    <Type>ItemAdding</Type>
    <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
    <Class>Class/Class>
    <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
  </Receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to register an event receiver to a specific list by URL, you have to specify the `ListUrl` property, like this:

```
<Receiver ListUrl="Lists/YourList">
    <!-- the rest of your code --> 
</Receiver>
```

If your list URL is different, change it accordingly.

Comment: yes buts its a document library

Comment: It's the same. As I said, change the Url accordingly. If it's a doc library, it usually is ListUrl="YourDocLib"

Comment: its drafts?.... this is my list url authoring/Drafts/Forms/AllItems.aspx

Comment: what's "authoring" ? Is it a site url or what?

Comment: then, yes, it should read ListUrl="Drafts"